# fields_for Accessing Associations of Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I have a set of models and their associations like this:

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one  :B
    has_many :X
end

class B < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :A
end

class X < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :A
end
```

I want to access X through A in a form, using simple_form_for.

```
<%= simple_form_for(@b) do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :b_field %>

    <%= f.fields_for **:A.X** do |x| %>
        <%= x.input :x_field %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I figure that if I was just accessing it in a controller, or helper, I'd be doing something like this

```
def func
    b = B.new
    x = b.A.X.first()
end
```

Can anyone shed some light on this for me, please?

**Update to add some more context:**

Class A is effectively an account class, it contains all the info necessary for a certain account type.

Class X contains images and was associated with Class A to hold all the pictures for the account.

Class B was added because it became necessary to have another type of account with different info from Class A, but because a ton of info was duplicated it was decided to keep Class A as the root account record and store the new info in Class B.

Now a requirement has appeared for Class B to have images, so it seems the easiest solution is to use the association in Class A to manage this, but we need to go back through the associations to Class A.X. I was hoping to use the associations as its much neater, rather than just doing a hack to get it working.

**Question**

Just a thought, is the answer to this to use the through keyword like this?

```
class B < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :A
    has_many :X, through: :A
end
```

Comment: Can you give more context? I think the solution will involve changing your associations, but without knowing what you're doing, I can only speculate

Comment: It's going to be pretty hard to change the associations from what they are. This is legacy code which has been added to, there's a lot more cruft to each of these models than I'm showing here simply because it will confuse things, but I'll try and add some more explanation in the original question.